# what is $i^{i^i}$ and how does it not coincide with $i^{ii}=i^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Because if you follow the usual rules $a^{b^c}$=$a^{bc}$, then $i^{i^i}$ = $i^{ii}$ = $i^{-1}$. Is there another way to justify the answer, if this is the correct solution?

Comment: Note that $a^{b^c}$ should mean $a^{(b^c)}$, not $(a^b)^c$.

Comment: What is your definition of $i^i$ as a complex number?

Comment: How do you reconcile the answer you saw fit to accept enthusistically (i.e., 2 minutes after it was posted) with the remarks made in the comments on it?

Comment: **Strong Hint:** $$i^i = e^{\ln i^i} = e^{i\ln i} = k$$. $$\begin{align} \because e^{i\pi} + 1 &= 0 \\ \implies e^{i\pi} = -1 &= i^2 \\ \implies \sqrt{e^{i\pi}} = e^{(i\pi)/2} &= i \end{align}$$. $$\therefore \ln i = (i\pi)/2$$ $$\therefore k = e^{i(i\pi)/2} = e^{-\pi/2} = \sqrt{e^{-\pi}} = \sqrt{1/e^\pi} = 1/\sqrt{e^\pi}$$. $$\therefore i^i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^\pi}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you're thinking of is $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ (which often does not hold for complex numbers, although it does hold for positive real numbers), it's generally not the case that $a^{(b^c)} = a^{bc}$.

We have
$$i^{(i^i)} = i^{(e^{-\pi/2})} = (e^{\frac\pi 2i})^{e^{-\pi/2}} = e^{\frac\pi 2 e^{-\pi/2}i} \approx 0.947+0.321i$$
Whereas
$$i^{i\cdot i} = i^{-1}=-i$$
On the other hand,
$$(i^i)^i = (e^{-\pi/2})^i = e^{-i\pi/2} = -i$$

Comment: can you elaborate how $i^{exp(-\pi/2)}$ turns out to be $exp(i\pi/2)^{exp(-\pi/2)}$?

Comment: Because $i=e^{i\frac\pi 2}$, by Euler's formula.

Comment: "Note that while it is true that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$..." Since the question is concerned with complex numbers, I guess your $(a,b,c)$ are complex valued so, even before "noting" what you say, **how do you suggest to define the complex number $a^b$ when $a$ and $b$ are complex**? (This, crucial, point has been made countlessly many times on the site, but.)

Comment: And to follow up on Did's comment, even if you decide on a "canonical" interpretation of $a^b$, in general, **it is not true** that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

Comment: Just to elaborate, $a^b$ is a multi-valued quantity since you need to pick a branch of the logarithm to define it as $\exp(b \log a)$.

Comment: The opening sentence you added after remarks were made that your answer was not holding water, now make the rest of the post frankly absurd since you manipulate in the latter quantities that you warned us, in the former, were ill defined and you use in the latter the exact computation rules that your first sentence says are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
$$
(a^b)^c\neq a^{b^c}
$$

As an example, set $a=c=2$ and $b=3$ and evaluate both expressions.

$$
(2^3)^2=8^2=64
$$

$$
2^{3^2}=2^9=512
$$

Hope that helps clear up the confusion.

Comment: I'd only add that $a^{b^c} $ needs to be defined and it is conventionally defined as $a^{(b^c)} $.  Which doesn't equal $(a^b)^c$ unless $b^c $ happens to equal $b*c $.

Comment: See comment to other answer, to realize the suggested quantities do not even make sense for $a$, $b$, $c$ complex.

Comment: @Did I understand there are other issues when working with nonreal numbers. There was an algebraic issue over the reals that I thought was important to clarify.